# Is it possible to use tags for excluding instances in DataDog while creating a graph?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, datadog

I have DataDog with Amazon AWS RDS integration configured.

Is it possible to create a graph and use a tag to exclude some hosts from the result. I have let's say 100 hosts with tag *environment:live* and 10 of them are also tagged with tag *importance:ignore*. So I need to create a graph which will include metrics for 90 hosts that are tagged with first tag but don't tagged with a second one. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can configure widgets to exclude results by tags. You can do this by applying a tag prepended with a `!` to signify "not".

So in your case, you can set up your widget scoped over `importance:ignore` and then hit the little `</>` button on the right to expose the underlying query, and sneak a `!` in front to make it `!importance:ignore`.

[This doc has a nice example](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tagging/using_tags/?tab=assignment#notebooks) (although it's for notebooks, it works the same in dashboards as well).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But that is not exactly my case. I want to specify 100 result by the first tag, than exclude 10 from them by using *!importance:ignore* and that seems doesn't work because when I specify 2 tags in </> edit mode it treats comma as *OR* instead of *AND*.

Comment: I think this should still work if you scope by `environment:live,!importance:ignore`, or more precisely, `avg:my.metric{environment:live,!importance:ignore} by {host}` maybe? that should give you all the 90 hosts that have the environment:live tag and not the importance:ignore tag.  or maybe i'm misunderstanding something? if that _is_ what you're looking for maybe just let me know and I'll update my answer?