# Is there a way to create a graph in Datadog dashboard for excluding ec2 instances that do not have certain tag key

Tags: amazon-ec2, datadog-dashboard

Problem:
Need to create a Datadog dashboard where I can only show EC2 instances which do not have tag "terraform-managed:true" at all.

What did I try :
I tried below query taking reference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/61015284/11880679 but it seems to be not working :
avg:aws.ec2.host_ok{!terraform-managed:true}

What is expected to happen :
It should only show instances which do not have above tag (key/value pair)

What actually resulted :
It still shows instances which actually have that tag